# Wedderburn's theorem

Tags: rt.representation-theory

In M. Isaac:s "Character theory of finite groups", there is a proof of a statement of Wedderburn (chap. 1, theorem *1.15.(c)*). The statement goes like this:

> Let $A$ be a semisimple algebra and let $M$ be an irreducible $A$-module. Then … *(c)*: the map $x \longmapsto x_M$ is one-to-one from $M(A)$ onto $A_M \subseteq \operatorname{End}(M)$.

Note that $M(A)$ is the $M$th homogenous part of $A$, that is, the sum of all submodules of $A$ isomorphic to $M$, where we give $A$ the right $A$-module structure.

Another comment: $A_M$ here denotes the image of the map $f:A \to \operatorname{End}(M)$, defined explicitly by $x \longmapsto x_M \in \operatorname{End}(M)$, where $x_M(m) = mx$ for $m \in M$.

The proof goes like this:

> *Proof*. By *(b)*, it follows that $x_W = 0$ if $x \in M(A)$ and $M \not \cong W$. It now follows from the direct sum decomposition $A = \bigoplus_{M \in \mathcal{M}(A)}M(A)$ that for $y \in A$, we have $y_M = x_M$, where $x$ is the component of $y$ in $M(A)$. We conclude that the map $x \longmapsto x_M$ maps $M(A)$ onto $A_M$. If $x \in M(A)$ and $x_M = 0$ then it follows from $(b)$ that $x$ annihilates every irreducible, and hence every completely reducible $A$-module. Thus $x = 1x \in A^{\circ}x = 0$, and *(c)* is proved.

*(b)* here refers to the statement "If $W$ is irreducible, then it is annihilated by $M(A)$, unless $M \cong W$".

$A^{\circ}$ is $A$ with the *right* $A$-module structure, and $\mathcal{M}(A)$ is the set of isomorphism classes of irreducible $A$-modules.

I believe I understand everything, except the part where they show the injectivity of the map $x \longmapsto x_M$. Am I correct that for a semisimple algebra $A$, it is the case that the Jacobson radical $\operatorname{Jac}(A) = \{0\}$, and if $x \neq 0$, then since $x$ annihilates every simple right $A$-module, it follows that $\operatorname{Jac}(A) \neq \{0\}$, hence $x = 0$?

Comment: Sorry, as Gregory Arone pointed out to me, obviously $x = 1x \in A^{\circ}x = 0$ implies that $x = 0$, by definition of the ring-operations in $A$.